# Firebase model POJO getter returns null in FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have a FirebaseRecyclerAdapter fetching data from the firebase database but when I am trying to access firebase data the getter method of the POJO returns null. I am able to get the database reference key.

```
    final Query beveragesQuery = mDatabaseReference.child(FirebaseValues.PRODUCTS)
                    .child(FirebaseValues.BEVERAGES);
            FirebaseRecyclerOptions<GenericProductModel> beveragesOptions =
                    new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<GenericProductModel>()
                            .setQuery(beveragesQuery, GenericProductModel.class)
                            .build();
            adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<GenericProductModel, Combos.MovieViewHolder>(
                    beveragesOptions
            ) {
                @NonNull
                @Override
                public Combos.MovieViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                            .inflate(R.layout.cards_cardview_layout, parent, false);
                    return new Combos.MovieViewHolder(view);
                }

                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Combos.MovieViewHolder viewHolder, int position, @NonNull GenericProductModel model) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Item received:"+getRef(position).getKey());
String json = new Gson().toJson(model);
                Log.d(TAG, "Item received:"+ json);
                Log.d(TAG, "Item received:"+ model.toString());
                    if (tv_no_item.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                        tv_no_item.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    Log.d(TAG, "card name:"+model.getCardname());
                    viewHolder.cardname.setText(model.getCardname());
                    viewHolder.cardprice.setText("₹ " + Float.toString(model.getCardprice()));
                    Picasso.get().load(model.getCardimage()).into(viewHolder.cardimage);

                    viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Beverages.this, IndividualProduct.class);
                            intent.putExtra("product", getItem(position));
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
                }
                @Override
                public void onError(DatabaseError e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "RV Adapter, Error occurred: " + e.getMessage());
                }
                };
            mLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            adapter.startListening();
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

My POJO or model class is

```
public class GenericProductModel implements Serializable {

    public int cardid;
    public String cardname;
    public String cardimage;
    public String carddescription;
    public float cardprice;

    public GenericProductModel() {
    }

    public GenericProductModel(int cardid, String cardname, String cardimage, String carddescription, float cardprice) {
        this.cardid = cardid;
        this.cardname = cardname;
        this.cardimage = cardimage;
        this.carddescription = carddescription;
        this.cardprice = cardprice;
    }

    public int getCardid() {
        return cardid;
    }

    public String getCardname() {
        return cardname;
    }

    public String getCardimage() {
        return cardimage;
    }

    public String getCarddescription() {
        return carddescription;
    }

    public float getCardprice() {
        return cardprice;
    }

    public void setCardid(int cardid) {
        this.cardid = cardid;
    }

    public void setCardname(String cardname) {
        this.cardname = cardname;
    }

    public void setCardimage(String cardimage) {
        this.cardimage = cardimage;
    }

    public void setCarddescription(String carddescription) {
        this.carddescription = carddescription;
    }

    public void setCardprice(float cardprice) {
        this.cardprice = cardprice;
    }
}
```

I am implementing Serializable because I am sending this data as an intent to other activity.

**Added some more log options for clearity** 
When I run the app the log output I am getting is:

```
03-17 15:05:55.200 4501-4501/com.vdeveloper.chaisutta D/BeveragesTAG: Item received, received:1
03-17 15:05:55.227 4501-4501/com.vdeveloper.chaisutta D/BeveragesTAG: Item received:{"a":0,"e":0.0}
03-17 15:05:55.227 4501-4501/com.vdeveloper.chaisutta D/BeveragesTAG: Item received:com.vdeveloper.chaisutta.b.a@63d3fc
03-17 15:05:55.227 4501-4501/com.vdeveloper.chaisutta D/BeveragesTAG: card name:null
```

Database Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution myself. The problem was with my POJO. As this project was on androidx I need to add the annotation "@Keep" to stop the compiler from removing methods which it thinks are redundant.

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import androidx.annotation.Keep;

@Keep
public class GenericProductModel implements Serializable {

    public int cardid;
    public String cardname;
    public String cardimage;
    public String carddescription;
    public float cardprice;

    public GenericProductModel() {
    }

    public GenericProductModel(int cardid, String cardname, String cardimage, String carddescription, float cardprice) {
        this.cardid = cardid;
        this.cardname = cardname;
        this.cardimage = cardimage;
        this.carddescription = carddescription;
        this.cardprice = cardprice;
    }

    public int getCardid() {
        return cardid;
    }

    public String getCardname() {
        return cardname;
    }

    public String getCardimage() {
        return cardimage;
    }

    public String getCarddescription() {
        return carddescription;
    }

    public float getCardprice() {
        return cardprice;
    }

    public void setCardid(int cardid) {
        this.cardid = cardid;
    }

    public void setCardname(String cardname) {
        this.cardname = cardname;
    }

    public void setCardimage(String cardimage) {
        this.cardimage = cardimage;
    }

    public void setCarddescription(String carddescription) {
        this.carddescription = carddescription;
    }

    public void setCardprice(float cardprice) {
        this.cardprice = cardprice;
    }
}
```

Thanks, everyone for helping

Comment: Good to hear that you found the solution. This used to be a bigger problem, but has gotten less prevalent over time. Sorry you got bitten by it, but I'm glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `null` because all your values are `null` since you are returning in each getter `this.fieldName` instead of the `fieldName`. To solve this, please change your getters to:

```
public int getCardid() {
    return cardid;
}

public String getCardname() {
    return cardname;
}

public String getCardimage() {
    return cardimage;
}

public String getCarddescription() {
    return carddescription;
}

public float getCardprice() {
    return cardprice;
}
```

See, there is no `this` anymore.

Comment: Actually I added "this" in desperation to make it work. I reverted back to using these getters and it is still returning null.

Comment: The only time you need to explicit refer to `this.cardname` is when you have a local variable with the same name. That **is** the case in OPs constructor and setters, where there's also a parameter with the same name. So there you do `this.cardname = cardname` to disambiguate between the field and the parameter name. But in the getters there is no such parameter, so the disambiguation is not needed.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I know when "this" is used but I couldn't find any other solution so tried that out of desperation. The POJO is returning null even after making the changes

Comment: @Developer97 Beside your POJO class, your code looks good to me, why do you say are still `null`, have done any other changes?

Comment: @AlexMamo NO, I haven't and it's making me confused too. I am able to get the key ref which means the data is being fetched I am just unable to parse it using my POJO.

Comment: If you override `toString()` method in your `GenericProductModel` class, what does this log statement `Log.d(TAG, "Model object: "+model);` print?

Comment: I only see an address there. Are you sure you have overridden the `toString()` method?

Comment: @AlexMamo I have updated the code too. you can see for yourself